# ASMX Web Service to Store User Data using SQL Server-SQL Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, web-services, asmx

Im trying to create an ASMX Web Service in Visual Web Developer.I have successfully Implemented the following

- Created a Database with columns Email,Name
- Created a Service

I have also specified connection string web.config like

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="mydb" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

But i get an SQL Exception "Incorrect Syntax Near @Name" after entering the data in the service form

```
[WebMethod]
public string insertuser(String UserName,String Email)
{

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
    sqlCon.Open();
    nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT  INTO UID (Email, Name) VALUES (@Email, @Name";

    // Add Parameters to Command Parameters collection
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);


    nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Email"].Value = UserName;
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Email;


    nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return "done";

}
```

Comment: have you really try to debug this? closing bracket is missing in insert statement

Comment: ditto it is nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT  INTO UID (Email, Name) VALUES (@Email, @Name";  and it should be nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT  INTO UID (Email, Name) VALUES (@Email, @Name)";

Comment: Thanks for the support.I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as andomar has correctly pointed out you are missing closing bracket in your sql command

just one thing you can generate insert command in you sql and just paste the generated sql into your code.

IE your code should look like

> nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT  INTO UID (Email, Name) VALUES
>   (@Email, @Name)";

Answer (score 0):

Add closing parenthesis:

```
VALUES (@Email, @Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your closing bracket:

```
VALUES (@Email, @Name)";
```